# Grouping Icons from Multiple Eclipse Installs

Tags: icons, eclipse, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I have two different Eclipse installs in my Ubuntu 18.04 with different plugins I create two `.desktop` files:

**Install A**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse Java    
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse_java/eclipse --class=Eclipse-Java
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse_java/icon_java.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment for Java
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse-Java
```

**Install B**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse Python    
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse_python/eclipse --class=Eclipse-Python
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse_python/icon_python.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment for Python
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Python;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse-Python
```

Both installs work fine, but I couldn't group the applications correctly.

[image: Sidebar print]

I know the problem resides with `StartupWMClass`, however, adding `--class` to the `Exec=` line won't change it.

The applications WMClass stays as "Eclipse", `# xprop WM_CLASS` returns `M_CLASS(STRING) = "Eclipse", "Eclipse"` after clicking on the running instance, even after using the class argument to run it.

Is there a way to fix that, letting me group the applications under the correct icon instead of having two Java EE new Icons?

Comment: Just to make sure, are the added `--class` and `StartupWMClass=` entry the same in your `.desktop` file (i.e. `--class CustomClassName` in the `Exec=` line and `StartupWMClass=CustomClassName`)?

Comment: Yes. Just Triple checked.